# How would I shorten these for loops?

Tags: c, for-loop, increment

So I've got a program that runs through every possible alphanumerical combination between 0000000000 and ZZZZZZZZZZ. Currently I'm using this code:

```
for (digit[0] = 0; digit[0] < 36; digit[0]++)
    for (digit[1] = 0; digit[1] < 36; digit[1]++)
        for (digit[2] = 0; digit[2] < 36; digit[2]++)
            // etc...
```

...and eventually there are 10 nested for loops and my entire editor screen is filled. So how would I condense this into one or two for loops? I can't find out how I would put them together testing and incrementing `digit[i]`. Thanks in advance to anyone who has this solution. I bet there's a million webpages on this but I couldn't think of how to phrase it in a google search.

Comment: You do realise the number of combinations involve that makes this impractical

Comment: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/recursion.html

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov yeah, it takes forever, that's one reason I need a better method here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an odometer algorithm. Increment the last digit. When it reaches the highest value, wrap it back to `0` and recurse on the remaining digits, until you run out of digits.

```
int increment_digit(int array[], unsigned int index, limit) {
    if (index == -1) { // We've wrapped around the entire set
        return 0;
    }
    array[index]++;
    if (array[index] == limit) {
        array[index] = 0;
        return increment_digit(array, index-1, limit);
    } else {
        return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int digits[SIZE] = {0};
    while (1) {
        // do stuff ...
        if (!increment_digit(digits, SIZE-1, 36))
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initial call should be `SIZE-1`

Comment: I made a function to print either a number or a letter. Where should I add it in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that uses a recursive function. You may have to adapt it slightly, as I had to assume some things - like the type of the array you're using.

Also, be warned that this will overflow if the for loop runs just one too many times.

```
void incDigit(int *digits) {
  digits[0]++;
  if(digits[0] >= 36) {
    digits[0] = 0;
    incDigit(digits + 1);
  }
}

int digits[10];
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < (int)pow(36, 5); i++) {
  for(i = 0; i < (int)pow(36, 5); i++) {
    //Code here  
    incDigit(digits);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `for()` loop won't work on 32-bit systems, because `pow(36,10)` is larger than `MAX_INT`, so `i < pow(36,10)` will always be true.

Comment: @Barmar interesting point. `pow` returns a `double`. AFAIK when comparing `int` to `double` the first will be cast to a `double`. So more likely there will be some redundant (or missing) iterations due to precision loss when casting `int` to `double`.

Comment: Eventually `i` will reach `MAX_INT`, then the next iteration will do `i++` and you'll get an overflow of `i`.

Comment: This is why my answer has the recursive function return a boolean that indicates when it has completely wrapped around.